# SQLiteOpenHelper variable initialization/use throughout the app

Tags: android

I have a little concern about how I handle my database in my apps, here is basically what I do:

I have a custom class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` that handles all the transactions with the DB.

In my app, I have one single `Activity` and several `Fragments` that are created, deleted, hidden or shown during the process.

In every `Fragment` where I need to modify or access data from the DB, I declare a static variable:

```
private static DatabaseHandler mDB;
```

And I initialize it this way on the `onCreate()` methods:

```
mDB = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getActivity());
```

All this is working, my concern is about the variable itself, is it a good idea to declare it as a static variable in all my custom fragment classes?

I also use the same way a class containing the main parameters of the app using `mParams = Parameters.getInstance(getActivity());`, should I also declare it as static?

I want to avoid memory leaks and NPE but I am not sure what is the right way to handle that.

FYI, the beginning of my `DatabaseHandler` class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DatabaseHandler sInstance = null;

(...)

private Resources mResources;

public static DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private DatabaseHandler(Context context) {  
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mResources = context.getResources();
}

(...)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I normally create a `SQLiteDatabase` static instance in my `Application` class and access across the app.

So , I have a custom class which returns `SQLiteDatabase` instance on application create.

This is my Application class

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

   private static SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        SQLiteAsyncTask sqLiteAsyncTask = new SQLiteAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
        mSQLiteDatabase = (SQLiteDatabase) sqLiteAsyncTask.loadInBackground();
     }

      // method to get the sqlite db instance
      public SQLiteDatabase getSQLiteInstance(){
         return mSQLiteDatabase;
      }
 }
```

Now you can get the `SQLiteDatabase` instance from Activity or Fragment , by

```
         MainApplication.getSQLiteInstance()
```

Comment: I read several answers saying that it is better to avoid extending the `Application` class, and the Android documentation also states: `There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way.` (source: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html))

Comment: I don't think extending `Application` creates any issue, since e.g., loading the database when the app starts is good to do in Application class rather doing from an Activity.